# getting the DefaultMessageListenerContainer from within the listener

Tags: java, spring, queue, jms, spring-jms

I have the following configuration :

```
<jms:listener-container container-type="default" connection-factory="cachedConnectionFactory" acknowledge="auto">
     <jms:listener id="myListenerContainerId" destination="myDestination" ref="myListener" method="onMessage" />
</jms:listener-container>

<bean id="myListenerId" class="X.Y.Z.myListener">
    // Some attributes
</bean>
```

And the following listener :

```
public class myListener implements MessageListener {

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    // Some work
    } 
}
```

Is there a way to get the *DefaultMessageListenerContainer* `myListenerContainerId` from within my listener ?

To clarify my needs, the listener `onMessage` is getting triggered whether `myListenerId` is running or not, active or not. I need to check if it's triggered only from `myListenerContainerId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; but if you add `new RuntimeException().printStackTrace()` you can see where it is called from.

Or you could examine the thread name (which has `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` in it, by default).

Comment: Great, Thanks :)